# Iterate over HashMap to add JMenuItem(s) to JMenu(s)

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jmenu, jmenuitem

I need to add the same JMenuItems to two different JMenu(s), but my code doesn't work properly.

```js
    private void addToMenu(JMenu m, JMenu m2) {
        for (Entry<Integer, JMenuItem> item : items.getJMenuItems().entrySet()) {
            JMenuItem i = item.getValue();
            m.add(i);
            m2.add(i);
            item.getValue().addActionListener(new ChangeColorOnClick(ground.getColorByValue(item.getKey()), textArea));
        }
```

The problem is that JMenuItems are added to `m2` menu only, like the second menu takes added items from `m` because `m` is empty. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know a component can have only one parent. That's why you see it only on the second menu... 
So what you have to do is to create separate menu item, re-using the same action object.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found useful is to create new object that contains collection of `JMenuItem`(s) for each `JMenu` I need to fill with items.